# Is there any way to find a distance between contour?

Tags: python, opencv, distance, contour

I got the binary image by python(opencv) and try to find the distance between each contour as following.
For this example,

[image: Binary image]

I would try to measure each contour distance of each line like this:

[image: red arrow loop to get distance]

Is there any way to catch the each contour point and get the distances I marked as red arrow and extend to  each line (1st,2nd.....nth)

I tried to use for loop to catch each point but I don't know how to automatically measure the distance like this (1st<-->2nd,2nd<--->3rd,。。。。。。nth-1<-->nth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the expected input is always a stripe pattern, you can loop through the pixels line by line. When a pixel is unlike the previous, note the number of pixels that were equal.

I created an example, where I use a small part of the original image - for clarity.

Input:

[image]

Result:

> [[6, 10, 8, 10, 8, 8],
>     [6, 10, 8, 10, 8, 8],
>     [6, 10, 8, 10, 8, 8],
>     [7,  9, 8, 10, 8, 8],
>     [7,  9, 8, 10, 8, 8]]

Code:

```
import cv2
# load image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('YDsdI.png',0)
# create small subimage
subimg = img[100:105,95:150]
# create empty list
all_distances = []
# loop all lines, then each pixel
# if the current pixel differs from the previous,
# then append the number of pixel that where equal
for line in subimg:
    start = 0
    line_distances = []

    for i in range(1,len(line)):
        if line[i] != line[i-1]:
            line_distances.append(i-start)
            start = i
    all_distances.append(line_distances)
# print result
print(all_distances)
# draw gray rectangle around the smaller subimage
cv2.rectangle(img,(95,100),(150,105),(127),2)
# show image
cv2.imshow('Img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```